# Email is Submitting Without ".com or .in" After Laravel Validation How to Fix This

Tags: laravel, validation, email

This is Form Input Feild :-

```
<div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-field ">
                                    <label for=" email validationCustom01">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="off">
                                    {!! $errors->first('email', '<div class="error-block" style="color:red">:message</div>') !!}

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This is validation in Controller :-

```
  return Validator::make($data, [
        'full_name' => ['required', 'regex:/(^[a-zA-Z\s]+$)/u', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users','regex:/^.+@.+$/i'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        'confirm_password' => ['required_with:password', 'same:password'],

    ]);
```

But Still Acception Something@Something as Valid Email How to Manage This Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you want to validate emails with a .com or .in specifically ?

Comment: yes Sir need to validate email with .com or .in

Answer (score 2):

You can use laravel default email validations.You can check laravel [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-email) as well, try something like this.

```
 "email" => "required|email:rfc,dns,filter,spoof",
```

Or you can use `ends_with`  as well . According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ends-with)

```
"email" => "required|email:ends_with:.com,.in",
```

Comment: @NikhilShukla your issue resolved ?

Comment: Yes Sir By Using "email:rfc,dns,filter,spoof" this

Comment: Yes I post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove regex from email field

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
        'full_name' => ['required', 'regex:/(^[a-zA-Z\s]+$)/u', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        'confirm_password' => ['required_with:password', 'same:password'],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "email" => "required|email:rfc,dns,filter,spoof",
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.